# Matrix class: unknown problems in C++

Tags: c++, class, memory, matrix, constructor

My program compiles but has these problems:

It's not using the member function `fill` (now). When i got the `fill` function to work (a while ago), it didn't do adding, subtracting, and multiplication correctly because it didn't record the second matrix it was supposed to do those things with. I got it to work the way you see it now, but this is the result:

```
ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./matrix
2 
2 
enter the matrix element by element(starting from the first row) 
1 
2 
1 
2 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If someone can point out the mistakes, it would be greatly appreciated:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class matrix
{
private:
    int r;
    int c;
    double** arr;
    double** arr2;
public:
matrix()
{
    r = 1;
    c = 1;
    arr = 0;
    arr2 = 0;

}

matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    r = row(r);
    c = column(c); 
    arr = new double* [r];
    for(int i =0; i<r; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new double[c];
    }
}

matrix(matrix& a)
{
    r = a.row(r);
    c = a.column(c); 
    arr = new double* [r];
    for(int i =0; i<r; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new double[c];
    }
}

~matrix()
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < r ; i++ )
    {
        delete [] arr[i];
    }
    delete [] arr;
}

void copy()
{
    arr2 = new double* [r];
    for(int i =0; i<r; i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = new double[c];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            arr2[i][j] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int row(int r)
{
    return r;
}

int column(int c)
{
    return c;
}

void fill(const int& r, const int& c)
{
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void print()
{
    for (int i=0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void sum()
{
    double ** arr2 = arr;
    cout << "enter the matrix you want to add" << endl;
    fill(r, c);

    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = (arr2[i][j] + arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    print();
}

void sub()
{
    double ** arr2 = arr;
    cout << "enter the matrix you want to subtract" << endl;

    fill(r,c);  

    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = (arr2[i][j]) - (arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    print();
}

void multiplication()
{
    double ** arr2 = arr;
    cout << "enter the matrix you want to multiply by" << endl;
    fill(r,c);
    int k =0;
    double ** arrm = arr;

    for(int i=0;i< r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j< c;j++)
        {
            arrm[i][j] = 0;
            for(k=0;k< r;k++)
            {
                arrm[i][j] = arrm[i][j] + arr2[i][k] * arr[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    print();
}

bool check(const int r, const int c)
{
    if(r==c)
    {return true;}
    else
    {return false;}
}

void get_det(const int r, const int c)
{
    if(check(r,c) == true)
    {
        int n = r;
        Determinant(arr,n);
        cout <<"the determinant is: "<<  endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "can't" << endl;
    }
}

double Determinant(double** arr, int n)
{
    double det = 0;
    double** m = NULL;
    if (n == 1)
    { det = arr[0][0];}
    else if (n == 2)
    {
        det = arr[0][0] * arr[1][1] - arr[1][0] * arr[0][1];
    }
    else if (n == 3)
    {
        det = arr[0][0]*(arr[1][1]*arr[2][2] - arr[1][2]*arr[2][1])
            + arr[0][1]*(arr[1][2]*arr[2][0] - arr[1][0]*arr[2][2])
            + arr[0][2]*(arr[1][0]*arr[2][1] - arr[1][1]*arr[2][0]);
    }
    else if (n > 3)
    {
        for (int j1=0;j1<n;j1++)
        {
            m = new double* [n-1];
            for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
                m[i] = new double[n-1];

            for (int i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
                int j2 = 0;
                for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    if (j == j1) continue;
                    m[i-1][j2] = arr[i][j];
                    j2++;
                }
            }

            det += pow(-1,1+j1+1) * arr[0][j1] * Determinant(m,n-1);

            for (int i=0;i<(n-1);i++)
                delete m[i];
            delete m;
        }
    }
    return(det);
}
};

int main()
{
    int r,c,answer;
    cin >> r >> c;
    matrix g(r,c);
    cout << "enter the matrix element by element(starting from the first row)" << endl;
    g.fill(r,c);
    cout << "do you want add  (1=yes / 0=no)" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if(answer == 1)
    {
        g.sum();
    }
    else{}
    cout << "do you want subtract  (1=yes / 0=no)" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if(answer == 1)
    {
        g.sub();
    }
    else{}
    cout << "do you want multiply  (1=yes / 0=no)" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if(answer == 1)
    {
        g.multiplication();
    }   
    else{}
    cout << "do you want to know the determinant  (1=yes / 0=no)" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if(answer == 1)
    {
        g.get_det(r,c);
    }
    else{}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? Also, in the parameterized constructor, instead of writing `r = a.row(r);`, you can simply write `this.r = r;`.

Comment: ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./matrix
2
2
enter the matrix element by element(starting from the first row)
1
2
1
2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: In your parameterized constructor, r and c are not defined when they are passed into the row() and collumn() functions. You should set r and c to the rows and columns variables that you passed into the constructor.